# Using output from one ruby script in another

Tags: ruby

I have written a ruby file that already does a series of work and prints out a ton of information, one sting per line (like "aa.bb:zz//"). Am I able to use that output via another script? I.E I want my next script to do the same exact thing with each line. To be more descriptive: Instead of

```
   $newscript.rb FIRSTLINE
```

I want the script to do it locally within itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about on the command line? What operating system are you using? If Linux, I think you want to pipe the output to [`xargs`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_xargs.htm).

Comment: I meant for the new ruby script the fetch the data provided by the oder one.

Comment: Does the second script only operate on one line, or can it take all the output from the first one at once?

Comment: If it can only take one line at a time, try `oldscript.rb | xargs newscript.rb` . If it can take the whole output, try `oldscript.rb | newscript.rb`

Comment: Or you could have the new script call the old script using `system("/path/to/oldscript.rb")` and use the output from that method.

Comment: simply require the code in the second script, see my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to split up your code is to use two files and require 'first.rb' within the second. That way you have access to the methods within. Simply execute those new methods and walla you have the output to use.

This first script will print it's status.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# first.rb
# Author: Andy Bettisworth
# Description: Declare first script status

class FirstScript
  def status
    counter = 1
    puts "I'm number #{counter}"
    counter
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  script = FirstScript.new
  script.status
  #=> I'm number 1
end
```

This second script will print both the first and second status.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# second.rb
# Author: Andy Bettisworth
# Description: Chime in after first 

require_relative 'first.rb'

class SecondScript
  def status
    first    = FirstScript.new
    counter  = first.status
    counter += 1
    puts "I'm number #{counter}"
    return counter
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  script = SecondScript.new
  script.status
  #=> I'm number 1
  #=> I'm number 2
end
```